# What is the origin of the word "wash" to mean a net gain of zero?

Tags: etymology, north-american-english

"Wash"

> A situation in which gains and losses balance each other

This appears to be informal North American usage. What is the origin of this use of "wash" to mean a net gain of zero?

Comment: The hints are vague, but some hits on Ngram give the impression that this derives from "wash-out", meaning a gully formed by a rainstorm.  This term transferred to sports, referring to an across-the-boards defeat, and the developed other meanings from there.

Comment: @Hot Licks This is on the right lines, I think.  Presumably, in such a case, on the trading floor the losses "wash" <out> the gains (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, an auction item that sells without making a profit or a loss is often said to have "washed its face". This has become more noticeable with the popularity of TV shows such as Bargain Hunt, and Antiques Road Trip.

I have traced this usage back to the 1930s via Google books.

In "Drama: The Quarterly Review", apparently from 1946, I found this:

> Which brings us to Glasgow - the real surprise packet.  In the dark
> days of 1941, John Stewart had the pluck to establish his tiny (106
> capacity) Park Theatre.  With a club subscription to help it washed
> its face in two years, specialising in first Scottish performances and
> taking a new play...

Another reference in 1949 in "Civic Entertainment" reads:

> When we went into this it was with a very rough estimate and we hoped
> to make good not by a large profit but being happy that we made ends
> meet, and the whole project "having washed its face."

However, in 1938 the phrase "washed its own face" was used in the House of Commons (UK Parliament), and documented in [Hansard](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/1938-05-19/debates/e74aacd7-a931-45f4-80bd-b548054b8814/HerringIndustryBill?highlight=%22wash%20its%20own%20face%22#contribution-f7e21ed2-ad47-4471-8542-6ad6bb805713), the official journal of the parliament

> The fishing season in the south-east of Scotland of which I am
> speaking is divided into three parts. The first starts about the first
> week in May, and that as a rule is very poor as far as earnings go.
> The second month is rather better, and the third month is, as a rule,
> good. A suggestion has been made that for the first month's voyage
> there should be an allowance made by the Unemployment Assistance Board
> to make up the deficiency between the unemployment scale and wages.
> During the second period it is calculated that the industry can, as it
> were, **wash its own face**, and it is suggested that during the third
> month the earnings should be reimbursed to the board after the needs
> of the men have been considered.

The "as it were" suggests that this was considered idiomatic usage at the time, referring to a business being sufficiently mature to be able to operate largely unsupported, and to cover its own costs.

My deduction from this, and other non-financial uses of the term, is that the maturity of the business is comparable with that of a child who is old enough to wash his or her own face, and starts to become less dependant on parental care.

Answer (score 0):

The usual sense of white-washing something fits nicely with the terms *wash trade* and *wash sale.*

> To whitewash is a metaphor meaning "to gloss over or cover up vices, crimes or scandals or to exonerate by means of a perfunctory investigation or through biased presentation of data".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewashing_(censorship)#:~:text=Etymology,entire%20interior%20of%20a%20barn. Definition borrowed from the Encyclopedia Britannica

This particular flavor of white-washing was well established by 1850.

I found examples of *wash trade* going back to the 1920s in the sense of stock market manipulation.

Here is a 1919 example of *wash sale* in the wholesale market.

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rubber_World/TqBEAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22wash+sale%22&pg=PA314&printsec=frontcover

One minor point. A wash does not necessarily mean a net of zero, only that there is an offset. If a baseball double header is a wash, then yes, it works out to zero, but more gradable things often wash to some remainder. There may still be fees for both sides of the transaction, for example.